# SelectParameters for IN Condition - Passing Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following in my `.aspx` file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KrySQL %>" OnSelecting="DataSourceSelecting"
       SelectCommand="Select ID, RoomNum from [dbo].[MBiology] WHERE LocId IN @LocId" >
    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="LocId" />
    </SelectParameters>        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My goal is to pass a comma delimited list or just one value for `@LocId`

In my code behind, I have the following:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["LocID"].DefaultValue = "(" + valint.ToString() + ")";
```

I thought this should work as I have the parenthesis and all.

I am getting the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '@LocId'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it like this: .NET does not let you pass an entire list in a single SQL parameter.

There are two ways of implementing what you need:

- Generating individual parameters for the members of the `IN` list dynamically, or
- Using [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) (requires an ability to change your DB schema to add a type).